# Is this statement correct "I want to buy another of this shoe"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Is this statement correct? "I want to buy another of this shoe"?

Comment: You mean you have only the left & you want the right? Or, you have an old pair & want a new pair the same?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, shoe retailers sell shoes by the pair. If there are specialty sellers who sell one shoe at a time, they are rarities, and some require a great difference in size before that policy kicks in. Some stores will sell you a second pair in a different size at a discount, if you happen to be one of those people whose feet are not the same size.

So you could say

> I would like to buy another pair of these shoes.

But you could refer to **this shoe** and mean "this style of shoe":

> Do you have this shoe in stock?

Unless you're in one of those rare places where shoes are sold individually, **this shoe** would not be understood to mean "this left shoe" or "this right shoe" in the given style.

This would also be idiomatic:

> Do you have these shoes in stock?